# CakePHP LDAP/MySQL Hybrid Model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, active-directory, ldap

I have a model (Person) in CakePHP which represents a user from a MySQL table.  One of the fields in the model is the user ID of a user in an Active Directory.  I have also implemented an LdapUser model, which correctly handles queries for AD objects, and uses the useTable = false setting.

I'd like to add a field to the Person model indicating whether the user is currently disabled in the AD.  I know how to do all the LDAP query business, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to add this attribute to the model.  My first idea was to add a static virtual field, set during construction of the Person model using the LdapUser model and ClassRegistry::init('LdapUser').  However, this doesn't work because virtual fields are just SQL aliases, and so CakePHP won't take the value I set for the virtual field literally. It instead tries to form it into the query.

Is there a way to set a static field value in a model, even if the model is reading from a database table?

Comment: Are you on CakePHP 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

The nice implementation would be a behaviour. That way you seperate all LDAP logic but still can access it via the Person model. The setup you have made now doesn't seem logic, there is one Person so that is one model. Better connect the LDAP part at the back of the model.

The your question about the disabled Person: You could for example load a behaviour with a beforeFind method. That way you could decide for example that users can never be loaded or you could add the disabled flag to the data.

In general just a method in the model called: isDisabled() should do the trick to answer your questions. There is not virtual field needed in this case.